# how to increase the number of English tweets fetched using twitter api in python?

Tags: python, twitter

I use the following code to fetch tweets from twitter and process it for the purpose of sentiment summarization . When I filter out the English words from the tweets for some queries only very little amount of data is remaining which is not enough for analysis. How can I increase the number of English tweets alone ?

```
from twitter import *
t = Twitter(

        auth=OAuth("<authentication codes>")
       )
t.statuses.home_timeline()
data = t.search.tweets(q=query)
for i in range (len(data['statuses'])):
         test = data['statuses'][i]['text'] 

         test = test.lower()

         test = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', test) 

         test = re.sub('@[^\s]+','USER',test)

         test = re.sub('((www\.[\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',test)

         test = test.strip('\'"')

         for w in test.split(' '):

             if detectEnglish.isEnglish(w)==True:
             print w
```

Comment: How many tweets "should" you get? How many are there before you filter for English words?